# Is there a jQuery version of Scriptaculous?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Scriptaculous is built on Prototype.  Is there an effects library similar to Scriptaculous, but built on jQuery?

There are many questions discussing jQuery and Scriptaculous, but none that directly address this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is called jQueryUI.

http://jqueryui.com